# Locust - Hatch Rate - EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, locust

I am using locust to load test an application. I wrote and tested the script on my local ubuntu system, and all went well.

I created an EC2 instance, using an Amazon Linux image, and after adjusting the file limits in /etc/security/limits.conf file I loaded up locust and things went normally for a small test (simple GET test, just to check the plumbing, 2000 users, 20 hatch rate).

However, when I loaded up a larger test, 8000 users 40 hatch rate, I noticed that somewhere around 3,000 or 4,000 users, the hatch rate appeared to slow down, just adding 4 - 5 rather the 40 new "users" at a time. So it took a long time to reach 8000. Is that expected behavior, if not, any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

What Locust calls "users" is actually gevent spawned TaskSets. This means you're spawning thousands of eventlets in a single Python process, which means a great deal of overhead managing those eventlets.

If you want to spawn thousands of TaskSets, I'd recommend running Locust in [distributed mode](http://docs.locust.io/en/latest/running-locust-distributed.html). You can have many slaves running on the same hardware, or distribute your slaves across many instances. Google has written up a neat article and open sourced some Kubernetes containers for just such a purpose. We wrote our own Docker container with Alpine and a heavily modified Locust, our ratio of slaves to TaskSets ended up being 1:100. The ratio of slaves to instances heavily depends on what instance size you get.